# Reference for cross-validation and Lasso

Tags: cross-validation, references, lasso, mathematical-statistics

Is there a main reference/publication suggesting to use cross-validation in order to choose the regularization parameter in Lasso?

Comment: The [original Lasso paper](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso/lasso.pdf) by Tibshirani discusses using cross-validation to choose the regularisation parameter in Section 4.

Answer (score 4):

You can try sec. 6.2.3 of James/Witten/Hastie/Tibshirani, Introduction to Statistical Learning

> ...
>   implementing ridge regression and the lasso requires a method for selecting
>   a value for the tuning parameter λ ... Cross-validation provides a simple way to tackle this problem. We choose a grid of λ values, and compute
>   the cross-validation error for each value of λ ... We
>   then select the tuning parameter value for which the cross-validation error
>   is smallest. (p. 227)

The canonical text for Lasso is probably Hastie/Tibshirani/Friedman, Elements of Statistical Learning, but ISLR is a good place to start for non-PhD level.